# Generate txt file with the specified order of the field based on the parameters of the input file

Tags: c#, json

I have a question regarding logic in C# of the following. I need to generate a file where the order of the fields are specified by the input JSON. For example, I have three fields in my output:

{ID, Name, Value}

The order of these fields are specified in the JSON file i.e.

```
ID = 1
Name = 2
Value = 3
```

So, if I need to change an order of the field I just do it in my JSON file which is added to the project.

Comment: What you have posted is not json at all. You have to post what you have and what you need.

Comment: Sorry for this, I thought my question is more about logic rather than details of the data. However, this is an example of JSON if that helps. Thanks. input JSON : "FileConf": [
 { "ID" = 1,
   "Name" = 2,
   "Value" = 3
 }
]   The output should be a txt file or csv file where the fields are in the right order based on the input json file - Id, Name, Value

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    var json = "{\"FileConf\": [ { \"ID\" : 1, \"Name\" : 2, \"Value\" : 3 } ]}";

    var jArray = (JArray)JObject.Parse(json)["FileConf"];
    var arr = jArray.Select(a => new string[] { a["ID"].ToString(), 
                              a["Name"].ToString(), a["Value"].ToString() });
    
    var sb= new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in arr)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Join(",",item));
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    File.WriteAllText("somefile.csv",sb.ToString());
```